# Using HoldForm for a changing list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a 'list' of the form an expansion: `F = (A[1] + A[2])(B[1] + B[2])`, such that `F[[1]]` produces the result

```
A[1]B[1].
```

Based on the values that appear in the brackets, I multiply the term with a certain term. I do this for each term in the `Expansion` of F, i.e. by using the iteration `Do[ ... , {i, 1, Length[F], 1}]`. However, when I multiply each term in F the ordering of terms change and I end up multiplying the same term more than once.

How could I use the `HoldForm` even when the list changes - where the change being the multiplication of each term in the list. I would want the order of terms to remain the same as the *initial definition of* $F$. Namely, I would like to multiply the first term of F by a predefined function that I have `Bra[2,0]` and so I obtain

```
A[2]B[1] + A[1]B[2] + A[2]B[2] + A[1]B[1]Bra[2,0],
```

but since I am iterating over each term (to multiply them) I would like for the outcome to instead read

```
A[1]B[1]Bra[2,0] + A[2]B[1] + A[1]B[2] + A[2]B[2].
```

In this way I would be able to change the second term of the 'list' and the whole procedure would be correct - you can see if I tried to change the second term of the list F when its order changes, I will be changing the wrong term.

I have seen similar posts, but not the case which makes use of the `HoldForm` function for a list changes. Thanks.

Comment: Something like `List @@ Expand [F]`?

Comment: I have tried to multiply each of the terms in `List @@ Expand [F]`, but the ordering of terms still change. I will make it more clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: `@Guesswhoitis`, converting the expression to a list does in fact work and I can achieve what I want through this method. However, would it be possible to still `HoldForm` for a list which changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to use `HoldForm` is to do something involving `Insert` like this:

```
F = (A[1] + A[2]) (B[1] + B[2]);

G = HoldForm[Evaluate@Expand@F];
Do[G = Insert[G, Bra[2, i - 1], {1, i, 3}], {i, 1, Length@Expand@F}]; 
G = ReleaseHold@G
```

> ```
> A[1] B[1] Bra[2, 0] + A[2] B[1] Bra[2, 1] + A[1] B[2] Bra[2, 2] + A[2] B[2] Bra[2, 3]
> ```

This process is a little simpler with the `Fold` operation:

```
G = HoldForm[Evaluate@Expand@F;
G = ReleaseHold@Fold[Insert[#1, Bra[2, #2 - 1], {1, #2, 3}] &, G, Range@Length@Expand@F]
```

> ```
> A[1] B[1] Bra[2, 0] + A[2] B[1] Bra[2, 1] + A[1] B[2] Bra[2, 2] + A[2] B[2] Bra[2, 3]
> ```

---

That said, I would still recommend the more natural *Mathematica* way recommended by [Guess who it is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is):

```
Total@MapIndexed[#1 Bra[2, First@#2 - 1] &, List @@ Expand@F]
```

> ```
> A[1] B[1] Bra[2, 0] + A[2] B[1] Bra[2, 1] + A[1] B[2] Bra[2, 2] + A[2] B[2] Bra[2, 3]
> ```